# Bump Maps are missing after exporting as glTF 2.0

Tags: .fbx, three.js, gltf

My goal is to export my entire FBX model into GLTF 2.0 format with all bump maps using Blender, and upload it online using Three.js

I've uploaded my FBX model to Sketchfab [https://skfb.ly/YOGv](https://skfb.ly/6BPZI) and it shows that my FBX model has the bump maps, however when I convert it to gltf using Blender, it doesn't show all the pieces of this model with the bump maps, I see it only on the bottom of my model, here's the site I'm displaying the gltf model using Three.js [http://virtualvizcaya.org/pages/1916barge_blender.html].

Please help! I'm also new to blender, but I'm open to other approaches to reach my goal. Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 3):

The glTF format uses normal maps, not bump maps<sup>1</sup>. If you can [bake your bump map into a normal map](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56638/how-to-generate-a-normal-map-from-a-bump-map) it should export correctly and appear the same. Sketchfab also allows you to download your model as glTF, so it may be worth trying that.

---

<sup>1</sup>The term "bump map" can mean different things, so I'm generalizing here... For a more precise answer I might need to see your material setup in Blender.